# Prove $\vdash\forall x(\alpha\to\beta)\to(\exists x\alpha\to\exists x\beta)$

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing, first-order-logic

I want to show that:

> $\vdash\forall x(\alpha\to\beta)\to(\exists x\alpha\to\exists x\beta)$

I started my deduction as follows:

> 1. $\vdash\forall x(\alpha\to\beta)\to(\forall x\alpha\to\forall x\beta)$ ---------------------------------- Axiom $3$
> 2. $\vdash\forall x\alpha\to\alpha$ --------------------------------------------------------- Axiom $2$
> 3. $\vdash\forall x\neg\alpha\to\neg\alpha$ ----------------------------------------------------- Axiom $2$
> 4. $\vdash(\forall x\alpha\to\alpha)\to\big((\forall x\neg\alpha\to\neg\alpha)\to(\forall x\alpha\to\neg\forall x\neg\alpha)\big)$ ------ Axiom $1$
> 5. $\vdash(\forall x\neg\alpha\to\neg\alpha)\to(\forall x\alpha\to\neg\forall x\neg\alpha)$ -------------------------- Modus Ponens $2,4$
> 6. $\vdash\forall x\alpha\to\neg\forall x\neg\alpha$ -------------------------------------------------- Modus Ponens $3,5$
> 7. $\vdash\forall x\alpha\to\exists x\alpha$ ------------------------------------------------------ Definition $\exists$

What is the shortest way to complete this deduction? Having shown that $\vdash\forall x\alpha\to\exists x\alpha$, how do I formally explain that $\vdash\forall x\beta\to\exists x\beta$ ? When I have these two statements, can I apply *Rule T* to $(1)$ to yield the desired proposition?

Comment: Can you do $\forall x\beta\vdash \beta$ and $\beta\vdash\exists x\beta$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Technically not, if I am to stick to the logical axioms listed page 112 in Enderton's _A Mathematical Introduction to Logic_ (2nd edition). So the lines $2$ to $7$ in my deduction are essentially a work-around that. My question is, since I have proved it for some wff $\alpha$, is there a way to justify that the same holds for some wff $\beta$ in one line, or do I have to do the same derivation twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to note that in Enderton's system $\exists$ is not primitive; thus, there are no rules for "managing" it.

We have use *contraposition* :

1) $∀x(α→β)$ --- assumed

2) $α→β$ --- from 1) and Ax.2 by *mp*

3) $\lnot \beta \to \lnot \alpha$ --- from 2) and **Rule T**

4)  $∀x(\lnot \beta \to \lnot \alpha)$ --- from 3) and **Gen Th**

5) $∀x\lnot \beta \to ∀x\lnot \alpha$ --- from 4) and Ax.3 by *mp*

6) $\lnot ∀x\lnot \alpha \to \lnot ∀x\lnot \beta$ --- from 5) "contraposing" again (i.e. by **Rule T**)

> 7) $\exists x \alpha \to \exists x \beta$ --- abbreviation.

Thus, from 1) and 7) we conclude by **Deduction Th** with :

> > $\vdash ∀x(α→β) → (∃xα→∃xβ)$.